# onClick in TimePickerDialog does not respond

Tags: android, onclick, timepickerdialog

I want to have a `ListView` where I can click on the single items. A `TimePickerDialog` should show up and let the user pick a time and also confirm his choice. So I used `setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, ...)` for this. The dialog opens up as it should, but if I click on any of the two Buttons, the dialog will just dismiss without leaving any message except for:

`sendCancelIfRunning:isInProgress=falsecallback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17@a929e50`

The buttonclick `Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Confirmed")` is never logged and the debugger also never even enters the `onClick()` of the `TimePickerDialog`.

```
public class AddStopActivity extends Activity {
    [...]
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        [...]

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.addStopSearch);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.medium_text_list_item, busStops);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                final Calendar myCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = myCalender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = myCalender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = (v, hourOfDay, minuteOfDay) -> {
                    if (view.isShown()) {
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfDay);

                    }
                };
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AddStopActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo, timeListener, hour, minute, true);
                timePickerDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_select_time);
                timePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

                int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.40);
                int height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.40);
                timePickerDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
                timePickerDialog.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Confirmed");
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
[...]
}
```

I tried logging and debugging the ButtonClick, but nothing showed any hints on what to do. I also tried calling `setButton()` after `show()`, but it also did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do this on the line where you set the button.

Instead, try doing the operations you want to do when the **"Confirm"** button is clicked in **"OnTimeSetListener()".**

```
//...
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = (v, hourOfDay, minuteOfDay) -> {
                    if (view.isShown()) {
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfDay);

                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "Time selected: " + hourOfDay + ":" + minuteOfDay);

                };

//...

                timePickerDialog.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Confirm", timePickerDialog);

//...
```

LOG:

```
Time selected: 18:10
```